# composer module it is git modified but it is not staged on git

Tags: php, git, zend-framework, composer-php

I have start a new project using `composer`. The project it is version tracked using git.

The thing is that I have install the component `"zendframework/zend-session": "^2.7"` and now when I try to perform a `git add vendor/zendframework/zend-session` and then I run the `git status` I get the following result:

```
On branch feature/install-session-manager
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   vendor/zendframework/zend-session (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

*Note: of course and I don't have modify the code of the files in the folder `vendor/zendframework/zend-session`*

Does anyone know how can I finally stage this modifications on my `git` repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need - and it's a very good practice - to add `vendor` folder to `.gitignore`

That way every developer can have a different local version of vendors and you don't need to store/retrive them into your `git` repo

To add it to `.gitignore` just put the string `vendor` in the file

To untrack previous files that are now under `.gitignore` just run

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Comment: Yes you are right and I know that, but while I try to create a plugin that requires all those libraries in order to be functional I have to keep them in track. I don't have in mind any other way to implement it without using this folder. What I create it is a WordPress plugin for personal consumption.

Comment: @MerianosNikos as you get `composer.json` file, you don't need whole `vendor` folder.

Comment: @ConCallisto thank you for your shared information. Do you have any resource explaining how can I configure the `composer.json` for using external libraries without need to use the whole `vendor` folder ?

Comment: @MerianosNikos you already have it, because, from your question, you stated that you have listed `zendframework/zend-session": "^2.7`. Everyone that will clone/fork your repo will run `composer install` in order to have the vendor automatically downloaded into the right place. This is the _raison d'être_ of composer :)